# Как убрать лишнее, и перенести нужное?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой код

```
$name = "family";
for($i=1; $i<7; $i++)
{
    $geter = $name.$i;
    $sql = "SELECT $geter FROM `21.02.18` ORDER BY $geter";
    $result_select = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    while($object = mysqli_fetch_row($result_select))
    {
        if($object[0] != '')
        {
            echo "$object[0]<br>";
        }   
    }
}
```

Он вытаскивает все фамилии из всех 6 столбцов.
Фамилии идут пример так:

- Карганов
- Пешков
- Никитенко
- Савченко
- Хайруллин/Агафонцев
- Карганов
- Савушенко
- Горелин
- Никитенко
- Горбуллин/Власов

Такие задачи:

1. Нужно, если обнаружен знак **/** разделить на 2 слова.
   Было: Хайруллин/Агафонцев, стало:

   - Хайруллин
   - Агафонцев
2. Удалить все повторяющиеся строки

   Если было в списке два Карганов'а, то должен остаться один.
   Тоже самое и с другими многими повторяющимися фамилиями.
3. Обработанный список отправить в столбик processed.
   1 ячейка - 1 фамилия.

Comment: Вместо вывода в цикле помещайте значения в массив, предварительно проверяя, что такого значения в массиве ещё нет. Там же перед добавлением стоит проверять строку на наличие разделителя `mb_strpos('/', $object[0])` и, если он есть, разбивать строку по этому разделителю `explode('/', $object[0])`. Потом выводите массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$arr = array();
while($object = mysqli_fetch_row($result_select))
{
    if($object[0] != '')
    {
       $object[0] = explode('/', $object[0]);
       $arr = array_merge($arr, array_flip($object[0]));
    }   
}
echo implode("<br>", array_keys($arr));
```

Как-то так. 
Должно роботать